# popup is opened before the action

Tags: jsf

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.action}" onclick="window.open('../note/note.faces', 'popupWindowName', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=450, width=700');">
```

In the above code popup is opened before action is completed when click the link.

is it possible to open after action is completed?

Answer (score 2):

Just move the logic to be executed to the target page of the action.

First remove the `onclick`:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.action}">
```

Then extend your `Bean` as follows:

```
private boolean executed;

public String action() {
    executed = true;
    return "targetpage";
}

public boolean isExecuted() {
    return executed;
}
```

And finally display the JS code conditionally based on `#{bean.executed}`:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.executed}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.open('../note/note.faces', 'popupWindowName', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=450, width=700');
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I want to put one link and in the above code where to mention the action.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand my answer. I've improved the answer.

Comment: @BalusC, here I do not understand how do you do the conditional display of JS based on bean.executed. I guess JS would execute whether bean.executed is true or false. So how to display the javascript part?